# Lilypond: new staff on same vertical line as previous staff

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to do some space-saving in some choral responses I've written. There there are 2 two-note phrases (A-men | A-men ). I'd like them to line up with each other to give the effect of being on the same line of music, at the moment they are reprinted on a new line.

While this could be achieved by making the whole phrase two bars and putting a double barline (or other barline) in between, I'd much rather have a new staff between the two one-bar phrases. For example, the last page of the [Ayleward Responses](http://www2.cpdl.org/wiki/images/4/43/Ayleward_Preces_and_Responses.pdf) where there are in fact three staffs on a single horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe putting a whole score into a markup could do the trick.

```
smallScore = \markup{
  \score{ \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { c' d' e' f' }
    \new Staff { c' d' e' f' }
    \new Staff { c' d' e' f' }
    \new Staff { c' d' e' f' }
          >>

          \layout {
            line-width=4\cm indent=1\cm
          }
  }
}

\markup{\concat { \smallScore \smallScore \smallScore }}
```

[image]